How to acheive true wildcard functions in python
For python classes it is possible to define the __getattr__() method to be able to call any function using that class.
ex:
# testclass/__init__.py
def x(*args, **kwargs):
    print("hello")

def __getattr__(name):
    return x

can be use like this:
# main.py

import testclass
testclass.thismethodshouldntexist() # -> prints "hello"

Is it possible to modify the global scope of a python script to be able to achieve a similar result without having to go through a custom class? I have tried modifying sys.modules[__name__], but can't seem to get it to do anything. I'm guessing that sys.modules only represents a reflection of what actually exists below the surface, and that it doesn't return the actual objects the python interpreter uses.
to be clear, what I want to achieve is:
# main.py
def x(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

# do some magic stuff

y() # runs x instead as y is not specifically defined

I understand that this probably is a very bad idea to use in any form of production code, I just want to learn more about how python works, and messing around with internal structures is usually a good way to learn

"For python classes" - That code is for a module, not a class

"I have tried modifying sys.modules[__name__]" - Please show your code so that we don't have to repeat your research. If there's too much, maybe just show your best attempt or two.

I might have an answer, but first I'd like clarification about module vs class.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.call

@ganz What does that have to do with the question?

What do you mean by "wildcard function"? I googled it, but from a quick look, all I can find are functions that operate on wildcards.

@wjandrea They described it clearly in the question. They want a value that will be returned as a default for any undefined global variable. What they're doing is not really specific to functions, since python uses the same lookup mechanism for variables and functions (it's used as a function when you put () after it).

@Barmar That's what I assumed too, but I'm not sure why they used the word "wildcard" since it implies metasyntactic symbols (like * or [ ]). I also want to clarify if they mean y is the "wildcard function" or __getattr__.

"wildcard" is often generalized to mean "something that matches everything", it's not just the syntax for it. It comes from the card game metaphor, where some cards (like Joker) can be used in place of any card.

@wjandrea I'm sorry I used the wrong term with class <-> module, but I don't think it is relevant to this question.
A "wildcard function" is as Barmar excplained just "any function". What I want to achieve is to have no function I try to run to be undefined, and instead mapped to the function x().
I am however not able to set __getattr__() for sys.modules[__name__] as it returns that it is read only.

@Pownyan OK, please [edit] the question to clarify it

With CPython, the value of a name not found in any static scope during compilation is loaded with the LOAD_NAME bytecode, which looks up the name in the namespace of locals, globals and builtins, in that order, in the current frame at runtime.
So if you want to customize name lookups with a default value, you would want the defaulting behavior to take place after failing the last lookup attempt--in the builtins namespace, which may be done if the builtins dictionary could be customized with a __getitem__ method that handles KeyError by returning the default value, which means that we need to replace the builtins dictionary of the current frame with one that has the custom behavior.
The problem here is that the only access we normally have to the builtins dictionary of the current frame is via frame.f_builtins, a read-only attribute, so replacing it is not possible via the standard Python API.
But for the sake of "messing around with internal structures" as your question desires, we can modify it with direct memory access via the ctypes module given the offset of the reference to builtins dictionary from the frame object, stored as the type PyFrameObject, defined as a type of struct _frame, which is defined as:
struct _frame {
    PyObject_HEAD
    PyFrameObject *f_back;      /* previous frame, or NULL */
    struct _PyInterpreterFrame *f_frame; /* points to the frame data */
    ...
};

where PyObject_HEAD is a macro defined as PyObject ob_base;, and PyObject is a type defined as struct _object, which is defined, after stripping the macros, as:
struct _object {
    union {
       Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
       PY_UINT32_T ob_refcnt_split[2];
    };
    PyTypeObject *ob_type;
};

And struct _PyInterpreterFrame is defined as:
typedef struct _PyInterpreterFrame {
    PyObject *f_executable; /* Strong reference (code object or None) */
    struct _PyInterpreterFrame *previous;
    PyObject *f_funcobj; /* Strong reference. Only valid if not on C stack */
    PyObject *f_globals; /* Borrowed reference. Only valid if not on C stack */
    PyObject *f_builtins; /* Borrowed reference. Only valid if not on C stack */
    ...
} _PyInterpreterFrame;

We can therefore calculate the offset of f_frame to a frame object, on a 64-bit platform, as 8 bytes for ob_refcnt, 8 bytes for ob_type and 8 bytes for f_back for a total of 24 bytes:
f_frame = ctypes.c_void_p.from_address(id(sys._getframe(0)) + 24)

and calculate the offset of f_builtins to f_frame, as 8 bytes for f_executable, 8 bytes for previous, 8 bytes for f_funcobj and 8 bytes for f_globals for a total of 32 bytes:
f_builtins = ctypes.py_object.from_address(f_frame.value + 32)

We can then replace the value of f_builtins with a proxy mapping that defaults to a specified value:
import sys
import ctypes
from collections import UserDict

def default_dict(value):
    class _DefaultDict(UserDict):
        def __getitem__(self, name):
            try:
                return super().__getitem__(name)
            except KeyError:
                return value
    return _DefaultDict

def x(*args, **kwargs):
    print("hello")

f_frame = ctypes.c_void_p.from_address(id(sys._getframe(0)) + 24)
f_builtins = ctypes.py_object.from_address(f_frame.value + 32)
f_builtins.value = default_dict(x)(f_builtins.value)

y()

This outputs:
hello

Demo here

This is amazing! I had no idea it was possible to actually modify pointer values this way in python.
Do you have any recommendations of good books or other resources that go into more details about how Python (or in this case CPython) works under the hood?
